# Python geopandas - nan values on the map

Tags: python, pandas, label, nan, geopandas

Now this part of code gives me figures for each cells on each map region, even on these which has no data at all. How to show it only for regions which has values in initial table?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

...

variable = 'price'
vmin, vmax = 10,90
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))

axK = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
mergedK.plot(column=variable, cmap='Blues',
            vmin=vmin,
            vmax=vmax,
            linewidth=0.8, ax=axK, edgecolor='0.8')

for _,region in mergedK.iterrows():
    axK.annotate(region['price'],
                  xy=(region.geometry.centroid.x,
                      region.geometry.centroid.y),fontsize=8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why not filter rows which has values in the initial table before plotting?

Comment: I think there should be another beautiful way )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest GeoPandas (0.7.0) handles missing value automatically. The easiest way for you is to update. By default missing values are not shown on a map, but you can specify style kwargs to show them in a way you like. See the [documentation](https://geopandas.org/mapping.html#missing-data) for more details.

To skip the annotation for missing value, just add this condition to your loop:

```py
for _,region in mergedK.iterrows():
    if pd.notna(region['price']):
        axK.annotate(region['price'],
                      xy=(region.geometry.centroid.x,
                      region.geometry.centroid.y),fontsize=8)
```

Comment: Thx for link and info about GeoPandas (0.7.0), now I know how to customise view of NaN regions, but it doesn't solve the issue itself, coz label's "nan" are still there on the every Nan region. As far as labels appers with this piece of code, I believe it should be changed somewhere here: `for _,region in mergedK.iterrows():
    axK.annotate(region['price'],
                  xy=(region.geometry.centroid.x,
                      region.geometry.centroid.y),fontsize=8)`

Comment: I edited the answer with the solution for annotations.